# how to convert weird text into specific word

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working on woocommerce api to add order manually.

I have ordered **variation** product manually and it shows good in edit order page in admin side.

Now, problem is the site using polylang plugin.

In that, there is two language. I can successfully add order in english language.

But when I tried to add product in another language(arabic). It returns some order details in weird text format. In my API it returns :

```
"product_variation_details": "%d8%a7%d9%84%d8%ad%d8%ac%d9%85: صغير"
```

In edit order page it shows in proper way: [image]

I have used below code to get order details in API:

```
$variation_id = $single_items['item_meta']['_variation_id'][0];
if ($variation_id != 0) {
    $variation = wc_get_product($variation_id);                
    $product_variation_details = wc_get_formatted_variation($variation->get_variation_attributes(), true);
}
```

I have search a lot but cant get better solution. any help would be apriciated. thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the question exactly? if the product name gets printed correctly, where do you need the name decoded?

Comment: @yivi I am working on API. At that time, I faced this issue.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking here. Please could you clarify what you expected to happen, and how it differs from what happened? I'm not sure there is enough info here to fix this for you; the problem is likely in code that you haven't included.

Comment: Can you please ask us exactly what you are facing really? It's an unclear question.

Comment: I am not sure what is wrong in this. It says "Size: Small". There is nothing wrong in decoding this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems that there is some decoding going on.
[Urldecode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php)

If I'm taking the given string and print it urldecoded it returns this:

```
print urldecode("%d8%a7%d9%84%d8%ad%d8%ac%d9%85");
الحجم
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing everything inside your `if` with:

```
$variation = wc_get_product( $variation_id );
$variation_attributes = $variation->get_variation_attributes();
$variation_attributes_decoded = array();

foreach ( $variation_attributes as $name => $value ) {
  $decoded_name = rawurldecode( $name );
  $variation_attributes_decoded[ $decoded_name ] = $value;
}

$product_variation_details = wc_get_formatted_variation( $variation_attributes_decoded, true );
```

This is untested.

This is the line from [wc_get_formatted_variation()](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-wc_get_formatted_variation.html#305-358) that is outputting your text in question:

```
$variation_list[] = wc_attribute_label( str_replace( 'attribute_', '', $name ) ) . ': ' . rawurldecode( $value );
```

As you can see, it's decoding the `$value` but not the `$name`. My solution should decode the `$name` ahead of time.

Edit: just fixed a code error.